# Solve $x(2^x+2^{-x})=\frac{17}{2}$ analytically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve $x(2^x+2^{-x})=\frac{17}{2}$ analytically? I was able to rearrange to get $x\cosh(x\ln(2))=\frac{17}{4}$ but can't get any further. WA gives 2 as the solution, but no steps provided.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it can be done?

Comment: @Jamie: For $x \gt 0$, we can reduce to $$(2 x)\left(4^x+1\right) =  (2^x)(17)$$ What value of $x$ gives us a value of $17$? Does that value satisfy both sides? You can also do analysis on both sides of the equation (do a plot) for a hint about how. An argument by exhaustion perhaps?

Comment: @Moo $x$ must be $>0$. All terms in your equation are $>0$ except the first.

Comment: Yes - that is why I state that in my comment.

Comment: @Moo Sorry, I read that as a condition. 'For $x>0$ we have [something] and for $x\leqslant0$ we have [something else]'

Comment: Sorry, I could / should have been clearer about that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as $4^2+1=17$, $x=2$ is an obvious solution.
Then as the LHS of Moo's solution has a term $4^x$ and the RHS $2^x$ the LHS grows faster than the RHS (or does this veer toward using using too much calculus?) so there can't be another equality as LHS will always be greater than RHS.

Comment: You lost some terms of the equation in the first line

Comment: Exactly, $4^2 \ne 17$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we know that the solution is an integer, there are few possibilities, as $x2^x$ grows fast. $x$ is certainly positive. $3$ is certainly too large, and it is enough to test $1$ and $2$.

If we don't know, I don't think there is an analytical way to solve, even using Lambert's $W$ function, which can solve $x2^x=\frac{17}2$ only.

Comment: I think the use of $x$ rather than something like $n$ implies that the solution can be a real number rather than an integer.

Comment: @Peter: you don't seem to realize that I am addressing both cases.

Comment: Sorry I misread

Answer (score 1):

First we simplify the question

$$2^x + \frac{1}{2^x} = \frac{17}{2x}$$

$$\frac{4^x + 1}{2^x} = \frac{17}{2x}$$

Assigning $2^x$ as $t$

$$\frac{t^2 + 1}{t} = \frac{17}{2x}$$

Comparing numerators and denominators

$$t = 2x$$
$$t^2 + 1 = 17$$
$$t^2 = 16$$
$$x^2 = 4$$
$$x = +2, -2$$

But, on substituting the obtained values in the main equation, we get only $x= 2$ as solution.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Ostergaard . I was struggling with that

Comment: What allows to infer, from $\frac AB = \frac CD$ that " $A=C$ and $B=D$" is true?

Comment: It's just a common assumption I was taught as both of them were variables. Plus, if you take a quadratic, you would arrive at the same conclusion

Comment: So, if I understand, you assume this in order to arrive possibly at some solution, not knowing however, whether this assumption is correct.Just a " heuristic" assumption?

Comment: Nope. As you might have seen from my previous comments, I did not know how to use math symbols and using a quadratic was difficult for me. So, I checked with this comparison and as the answers matched, I went with this one

Comment: As to symbols, if you " select" an expression ( with mouse and left clic) and then rightclic, you will be asked whether you want to see the " math jax" that is behind the printed formula. Doing this this can help you to get aquainted to the symbols.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll use that hereafter

Answer (score 1):

When $x\leq 0$,  there are no solutions because $x\left(2^x+2^{-x}\right)\leq 0$. Let $x>0$ and rewrite as
$$2^x+2^{-x}=\frac{17}{2x} $$
For $x>0$, the RHS is a strictly decreasing function ($a>b>0\Rightarrow \frac 1a<\frac 1b$). And we can show that the LHS is a strictly increasing function. Since $2^x+2^{-x}=2^x+\frac{1}{2^x}$ and $2^x>1$ when $x>0$, we need to show $t+\frac 1t$ is strictly increasing for $t>1$. Suppose $u>v>1$. Then
$$\left(u+\frac 1u\right)-\left(v+\frac 1v\right)=u-v-\frac{u-v}{uv}=(u-v)\left(1-\frac{1}{uv}\right)>0 $$ since $uv>1$. Thus, there can be no more than $1$ solution when $x>0$. We notice $x=2$ is a solution. That means $x=2$ is the only solution.